# How can I omit words in the middle of a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, string

I have a multi-line string like this:

```
"...Togo...Togo...Togo...ACTIVE..."
```

I want to get everything between the third 'Togo' and 'ACTIVE' and the remainder of the string. I am unable to create a regular expression that can do this. If I try something like

```
reg = "(Togo^[Togo]*?)(ACTIVE.*)"
```

nothing is captured (the first and last parentheses are needed for capturing groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This matches just the desired parts:

```
.*(Togo.*?)(ACTIVE.*)
```

The leading `.*` is greedy, so the following `Togo` matches at the last possible place. The captured part starts at the last `Togo`.

In your expression `^[Togo]*?` doesn't do the right thing. `^` tries to match the beginning of a line and `[Togo]` matches any of the characters `T`, `o` or `g`. Even `[^Togo]` wouldn't work since this just matches any character that is not `T`, `o` or `g`.

Comment: Duh... much simpler than my attempt.

Comment: In general this seems to be the best suggestion, but in my case it takes too much time. Still, I think this is the best approach if it's fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
reg = "Togo.*Togo.*Togo(.*)ACTIVE"
```

Alternatively, if you want to match the string between the last occurrence of Togo and the following occurence of ACTIVE, and the number of Togo occurences is not necessarily three, try this:

```
reg = "Togo(([^T]|T[^o]|To[^g]|Tog[^o])*T?.?.?)ACTIVE"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"(Togo(?:(?!Togo).)*)(ACTIVE.*)"
```

The square brackets in your regex form a character class that matches one of the characters 'T', 'o', or 'g'.  The caret ('^') matches the beginning of the input if it's not in a character class, and it can be used inside the square brackets to invert the character class.

In my regex, after matching the word "Togo" I match one character at a time, but only after I check that it isn't the start of another instance of "Togo". `(?!Togo)` is called a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).